# Oracle List of value (lov) refresh when select any row

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, lov

I have created a LOV on oaf page. The issue is when i select any row from LOV page, it's reloading the (lov) page instead returning the values to back page.

If we keeps opened LOV window for more than 5 minutes and then select any row, it works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of ADF are you using?

Comment: Oracle JDeveloper: 10.1.3.3.0

ADF Business Components 10.1.3.41.57
AOLJ FND R12.1.3 (8919491)
BPEL Designer 10.1.3.3.0 (Build 070615.0525)
BiBeans Runtime 3.1.1.10
Build Type Optimized
CVS Version Internal to Oracle JDeveloper (client-only)
Java(TM) Platform 1.5.0_05
MDS Runtime 9.0.6 (Build OJTMDS_9.0.6_NT_100323.1517.45)
OA Extension 10.1.3 (Build OAEXT_MAIN_NT_100429.1954.1314)
OA Framework 12.1.3 (R1213XB4_1_4)
Oracle IDE 10.1.3.00.03
Struts Modeler Version 10.1.3.41.57
UIX Runtime 2.3.6.9 (Build 100218.1937)
UML Modelers Version 10.1.3.41.57
Versioning Support 10.1.3.00.03

Comment: I checked this page in Mozilla FF. it works fine but in IE is not working properly.

Comment: You are probably one of the few running ADF version 10. That was a failure, from a technical perspective.  Probably there are reason why you don't upgrade, but I can't help, sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

In OAF, while creating an LOV, i.e., messageLOVInput item, lovMap is required to be set.
Make sure the LOV Region Item, Return Item and Criteria Item in this lovMap is set properly.

LOV Region Item : field from which value is picked from lov table

Return Item : field in which value should be set on selection from list of values

Criteria Item : field which is validated for value